Trouble setting up ocaml-lsp
I have ocamllsp already installed through opam. However, I'm not getting lsp features like errors when I put in the wrong type. I also can't install it through Mason: I get an error.
I've 'installed' kickstart.nvim and am using Ubuntu 22.04.

Is the question about Mason or something else? If there’s an error message, please include it. Minimal instructions to reproduce the problem would help. Please [edit] these details in.

Welcome to [vi.se]!
